# Export a class in Typescript and Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I'm creating a class in a separate file to import from the `controller`, but it won't let me declare variables inside the class.

This is the `class` I want to export:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const rimraf = require("rimraf");

export class createDir {
    let dir = 'src/output';
    if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        rimraf.sync(dir);
    }else {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
     }
}
```

This is the `error` that `let` shows:

```
Unexpected token. A constructor, method, accessor, or property was expected
```

**My problem**: how can I export the function in Typescript and what is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your original question is answered but you have further unrelated questions, it is best to mark that answer as correct then start a new question instead of taking on new questions. This keeps questions focused and easier to search for.

Comment: @JeffB The question goes inside the original question is just knowing how to get that name because I don't understand why it returns undefined

Comment: I will reply to your question, but understanding how to correctly reference imported classes and functions IS a separate issue to knowing how to export classes and functions =).

Comment: @JeffB Ok I understand, I will better review my questions, thank you. Can you solve just this last question for me to close the question? I am still somewhat stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a function in your class:

```
export class createDir {
  function checkExistsOrCreate () {
    let dir = 'src/output';
    if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        rimraf.sync(dir);
    }else {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir);
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, and now how do I export and import in another class, that is, how can I execute this function in another class?

Comment: I think you want your class to be a function, or the class should be called something like `file`.
To import in another file, you would `import {createDir} from "createDirFile"`
To use it, you would do `let x = new createDir();`
`x.checkExistsOrCreate()`

Comment: I have a problem now, I have added the following: let dir = new createDir (). CheckExistsOrCreate (); but it returns me undefined, how can I read the created src / output folder?